# Macro for Protecting All Non Blank Cells in xls in Folder

Tags: loops, excel, excel-2007, vba

```
Sub Divide() 
Dim fPath As String 
Dim fName As String 
Dim wb    As Workbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim pwd As String 
pwd = "can" ' Put your password here

 'Setup
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
fPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\TRSECCAN\2011\Excel\" 'remember final \ in this string
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls") 'start a list of filenames
Do While Len(fName) > 0 
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName) 'open found file
    With ActiveSheet 
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select 
        Selection.Locked = False 
        .Protect Password:=pwd 

    End With 
    wb.Close True 'close/save
    fName = Dir 'get next filename
Loop 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

I need a macro for Opening all the workbooks in a folder then for each sheet it will select blank cells, then make them unlocked then protect the sheet with a given password.

The upper code does this only for the active sheett, how can i make it for all the sheets the macro opens ? and Is there anyway i can deploy the below into the code

```
 UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Divide()
Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String
Dim wb    As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String
pwd = "can" ' Put your password here

'Setup
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 fPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\TRSECCAN\2011\Excel\"   'remember final \ in this   string
 fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls")    'start a list of filenames

Do While Len(fName) > 0
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever) 'open found file
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
With ws.Cells
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False

End With
With ws
.Protect Password:=pwd

End With
Next ws
wb.Close True                   'close/save
fName = Dir                     'get next filename
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have found the code to be useful so thanks everyone for contribution

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your code should look like (you should remove unneeded `Select`:

```
Sub Divide() 
Dim fPath As String 
Dim fName As String 
Dim wb    As Workbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim pwd As String 
pwd = "can" ' Put your password here

 'Setup
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
fPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\TRSECCAN\2011\Excel\" 'remember final \ in this string
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls") 'start a list of filenames
Do While Len(fName) > 0 
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever) 'open found file
    For Each ws in wb.Worksheets    
        With ws
           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False 
           .Protect Password:=pwd 
        End With 
    Next ws
    wb.Close True 'close/save
    fName = Dir 'get next filename
Loop 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

See [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/update-links.htm) for update links and [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) for loops

Comment: The parentheses on the ``Workbooks.Open`` line needs to be moved to the end (e.g. after the UpdateLinks parameter).

Comment: Thanks Rachel! (@RachelHettinger for notification :))

Comment: Thanks guys, with your help i wrote the code below. I posted it as an answer

Comment: @user768199: glad you eventually made it. Please don't forget to accept your own answer to "close" the thread

Answer (score 0):

This code will cycle through every worksheet in the active workbook displaying sheet names and the value of cell A1 to the immediate window.

```
Sub DisplayWSNames()

  Dim InxWS As Integer

  For InxWS = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(Inx)
      Debug.Print "Cell A1 of Sheet " & .Name & " = " & .Cells(1, 1)
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

I don't link workbooks myself so cannot help you with that part of your question.